# Phase difference approximation

Tags: optics, diffraction, approximations

I'm sitting and trying to solve the equation of the phase difference given by:

$\Delta \phi = k (\sqrt{a^2+d^2} -d) \approx \frac{ka^2}{2d}$

Where $a$ is the size of an aperture and $b$ is the distance of the point at the aperture's center as shown in the figure below.

[image: figure 1]

I'm not a math expert here, so I wondering if anyone can explain the approximation that has been done above here.

**Reference:**

Applications of Classical Physics by Roger D. Blandford and Kip S. Thorne - Chapter 8 - Diffraction

Comment: Warm welcome to physics stack exchange Kanthee Kosolyuthasarn! Nice to have you here. One suggestion I'd like to put for your post is to make the titles to be more specific to the doubt, so that the searchability of the post increases (it will help if someone else has a similar doubt ) :-)

Comment: @Buraian Thank you for your advice! I will be more specific next time. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need the binomial expansion
$$ \sqrt{d^2+a^2} \approx d \left(1+\frac{a^2}{2d^2}\right) , $$
which assumes that $d\gg a$.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After fixing the typo in your equation you can  use the binomial theorem
$$
\sqrt{1+x}= 1+\frac 12 x+\ldots
$$
to get
$$
k(\sqrt{a^2+d^2}-d)= k\left(d\left(1+\frac{a^2}{d^2}\right)^{1/2}-d\right)\\
 = k\left(d\left(1+\frac 12 \frac{a^2}{d^2}+\ldots\right)-d\right)\\
=k\frac{a^2}{2d}+\ldots
$$

Comment: Sorry for the typo! So, I can assume that $\frac {a^2}{d^2}$ is small, then I can binomially approximate (for small $x$, $\sqrt {1+x} \approx 1+\frac 12 x$). Thank you!